# Wordpress Website is Auto-Posting strange posts

Tags: posts

some days ago i mentioned, that the wordpress homepage I'm running is auto-posting different articles (e.g. with the title "Immediate Products Of RussiansBrides – An Analysis")

Technical info about the website:

URL: www.ecehrwald.com

Hosting Provider: serverprofis.net

Wordpress-Version: 5.2.2

Theme: Ample

Installed Plugins: Akismet Anti-Spam, Easy Social Media Widget, Elementor, Hello Dolly, Social Media and Share Icons (Ultimate Social Media), WP show posts

Does anybody know where the problem could be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: uhm. Your wordpress install *clearly* got compromised? Honestly - the right thing to do, especially if you have hello dolly installed as a plugin (Its default and does nothing) is to take it down *immediately* and try to work out what happened.

Comment: Wordpress and all plugins must always and immediately be kept up-to-date. Everyone uses Wordpress, making it an attractive target for attackers.

Comment: Your site got infected. You have to heal it and then secure it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can be hacked by someone and they automatically post their content on your site. When I had my own site I faced the same problem and [here](https://inspirationfeed.com/turn-your-papers-into-masterpieces/) I read an advice to change the password. Then it helped me, you can try.